# Adding virtual refs for repo hosted at github.com

Tags: git, github, gitolite

Does github.com has support for adding virual refs like gilote as discussed in [gitolite or gitosis: permission on directory inside of the repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047416/gitolite-or-gitosis-permission-on-directory-inside-of-the-repository) ?

I need to restrict access at directory level inside the repo.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

No, at least not as gitolite VREF.

On Github side, there are a [post-receive hook](https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks) or [webhooks](https://help.github.com/articles/testing-webhooks), but the are after the push.

The only way to really guard a directory within one Github repo is to make/export that directory in its own GitHub repo, and declare it as a [submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) in the first repo.

Comment: +1, but I would like to note that if you really need fine-grained control over stuff like that, github is probably not the correct hoster for your.

Comment: @Chronial right you are. You need to balance the need for a public repo and fine-grained control. The latter means setting up your own server.