# FATAL: W refs/heads/master DENIED by fallthru - Gitolite Folder permission setup

Tags: git, gitolite

I have Gitloite version 3 hosted on Amazon WS (Git v1.9.1/gitolite v3.6.1-6)

I have the following setup:

```
Acme-Repository
|
|------- <JEE>
|
|--------<Android>
|
|--------<iPhone>
```

I need to restrict the user's permission as follows to the folders:

```
•   Usera - Read/write - JEE  
•   UserB - Read/write - Android
•   UserC - Read/write - iPhone
```

I have got the following setup in the gitolite.config

```
RW+   Jee/      =  UserA
RW+   Android-App/  =  UserB
RW+   iPhone-App/   =  UserC
```

While pushing as `UserA`, I am getting the following error:

```
remote: FATAL: W refs/heads/master Acme-Repository UserA DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master
```

I've tried:

```
RW+   NAME/Jee/ =   UserA   
..

AND

RW+   refs/head/Jee/ =   UserA  
..
```

But both returned the same results. **What could be wrong**? I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980750/gitolite-permissions-on-branches), [this](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/g2/bac.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047416/gitolite-or-gitosis-permission-on-directory-inside-of-the-repository)

**Update - Now working configuration**

After Original Author Sitaram's answer on google groups and answer from @vonc - now I have the following and works like a charm:

```
@AllDevelopers          = UserA UserB UserC
@Jee                    = UserA
@Android                = UserB
@iPhone                 = UserC

RW+                                 = @AllDevelopers                                          
  -   VREF/NAME/Jee/                = @Android @iPhone
  -   VREF/NAME/Android-App/        = @Jee @iPhone
  -   VREF/NAME/iPhone-App/         = @Android @Jee
```

What the above configuration in human language means -

- **@AllDevelopers** group will have access to the repository, but
- **@Android** and **@iPHone** are denied access to **Jee** folder and subfolders.
- **@Jee** and **@iPhone** developers are denied access to **Android-App** folder and subfolders.
- **@Android** and **@Jee** developers are denied access to **iPhone-App** folder and subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protecting against files or directory is done by **[VREF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10888358/6309)** (see [gitolite doc](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html))

```
VREF/NAME/xxx
```

In your case ([`VREF/NAME` doc](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#NAME)):

```
@users = UserA UserB UserC

repo Acme-Repository

  # allow pushing to any branch for any paths
  RW+                         =  @users 

  # except for those specific paths:
  -   VREF/NAME/Jee/          =  UserA
  -   VREF/NAME/Android-App/  =  UserB
  -   VREF/NAME/iPhone-App/   =  UserC
```

Since a VREF is considered an "[additional deny rule](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html#vref-fallthru)", you need to allow access first (`RW+ @users`) *before* restricting access with VREF rules.
(Just saw [Sitaram Chamarty](https://plus.google.com/115609618223925128756/posts) -- author of gitolite -- [answer on groups.google.com](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gitolite/ohV0qhV-obk))

Comment: Thanks. I had already posted this is on Gitolite Google groups and Sitaram had answered it. But I am also accepting your answer as the answer is very good. Please see my update on the question on how it works now. Thanks again.

Comment: @avijendr I just saw it. I also saw that Sitaram isn't too fond of Stack overflow ;) (https://plus.google.com/115609618223925128756/posts/Zoo1EWCxWBE)

Comment: Yeah you are right he is not very fond of SO. He has got his reasons which I think is alright. He told me you are going to answer in SO :). Thanks again VonC.