# Does a git cloned repository on a specific branch contain all the other branches' information?

Tags: git, github

For instance, suppose a git repo has two branches, master and branchA, if branchA is cloned by using

`git clone --single-branch branchA`

can we recover branch master from the cloned repo? and can we see from the cloned repo history that there exists a branch master?

Comment: please take a look inside .git directory... the config file, HEAD, and the refs directory should be of interest. down-vote not from my side

Comment: Have you tried it? E.g., `git checkout master`

Answer (score 0):

The [`git clone` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---no-single-branch) can help:

```
--[no-]single-branch
```

> **Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or the primary branch remote’s HEAD points at**.
>   Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning.
>
> If the HEAD at the remote did not point at any branch when `--single-branch` clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is created.

Note: you can do that for a tag as well, but [do use a Git 2.11+ in that case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39527106/6309).