# Copying some branches of a repository into a new repository

Tags: git, version-control

We have a huge git repository (say it A )that contains many branches. I want to create a new smaller repository (say it B) that will contain few branches of A.

What I know is as follows

1. Clone some branches from repository A to local
2. Push these branches to repository B.

Don't we have some method to copy these branches directly from repository A to B?. Or some improvement to the above mthod?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fetch only one branch of a remote git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository)

Answer (score 1):

If you have direct access to repo `A`, you can directly the branch you want to a new repo `B`.

But if you need to clone A first, then a concrete example exists in "[Clone just the stable and one other branch in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615488/clone-just-the-stable-and-one-other-branch-in-git)", and uses the same tip than the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368987/how-do-i-fetch-only-one-branch-of-a-remote-git-repository) [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864065/copying-some-branches-of-a-repository-into-a-new-repository#comment26082422_17864065) by [mnagel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2536029/mnagel), with [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
 cd B
 git init .
 git remote add -f -t remote-branch1 -t remote-branch1 remote-name remote-url
```

Note the `-f` which, when used with `git remote add`, will immediately fetch `remote_name`.