# Add branch to the set of remote fetched branches

Tags: git, git-remote

I have a remote from which I fetch only one branch:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = ....
    fetch = +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/upstream/foo
```

I want to add another branch to the set of branches I fetch from this same remote.

I know I can edit local `.git/config` and add a second fetch clause by hand:

```
[remote "upstream"]
    url = ....
    fetch = +refs/heads/foo:refs/remotes/upstream/foo
    fetch = +refs/heads/bar:refs/remotes/upstream/bar
```

Ergo, I can invoke the `git config` magic to do same thing without editing the config file:

```
 git config --local --add remote.upstream.fetch +refs/heads/bar:+refs/remotes/origin/bar
```

Both approaches (mentioned, in particular, in [answers to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1615488/1149924)) look quite low-level to me. Is there a higher level git command to add a branch to the set of remote refs, just like `remote add -t <branch> ....` that was initially used to create the single branch refs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of.

The easiest way would be to script that "high level command" yourself, in bash (even on Windows), calling it `git-addfetchbr.sh` (to be stored anywhere in your `$PATH`).
That would allows you to type:

```
git addfetchbr upstream bar bar
```

The script would do a:

```
git config --local --add remote.$1.fetch +refs/heads/$2:+refs/remotes/$1/$3
```