# git clone specific list of branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone

I want to clone a list of branches from remote repo. What is the best way to do that without fetching everything?
I saw solutions for cloning one specific branch but I need multiple branches.
Thank you.

Edit:
I ended up using following command to create a bundle and then using it for my purposes:

```
git bundle create ../BUNDLE.bundle branch1 branch2 refs/notes
```

And then using this bundle for my purposes.

Comment: You can only work on one branch at a time, so why not simply run the command to clone a specific branch multiple times as needed?

Comment: What's the objection to fetching everything?

Comment: I want to create a new repo based on few branches of the original one. Fetching everything will not help my cause.

Comment: Duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1615488/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You start with one branch:

```
git clone --branch first URL localrepo
```

and then fetch all the rest:

```
cd localrepo
for branch in second third etc; do
    git fetch origin $branch:$branch
done
```

Or without loop

```
git fetch origin second:second third:third
```

Comment: why is there a colon, for example second:second and third:third?

Comment: @AndesLam You never read docs, right? Please do: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-ltrefspecgt

Comment: @AndesLam
git fetch <remote name> <remote branch name 1>:<local branch name 1> <remote branch name 2>:<local branch name 2> ...