# GIT: Clone only specific branches from GitHub

Tags: git, github, repository, git-clone

Is there a potential way to clone not complete repository from GitHub, but just selected branches? I've found single branch clone is possible with command:

> git clone git@github/path/to/repository.git --branch my_branch_1 --single-branch

So would like to achieve something like this:

> git clone git@github/path/to/repository.git **--branch** my_branch_1 **--branch** my_branch_2 --single-branch ??

It means only two of them. The issue is, that such repo is quite huge in the master branch and not needed for developers. They just need branches ***my_branch_1*** and ***my_branch_2***. From such branches developers should make their dev branch and later *pull request on GitHub* to the ***master***.

Maybe it's possible via git remote add or something like this. But I'm not so much familiar probably with the concept of Git internally.

Comment: Clone 1 branch then use git fetch to get the rest you need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone specific list of branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49039959/git-clone-specific-list-of-branches)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clone%5D+specific+branches

Answer (score 8):

There doesn't seem to a way to clone multiple branches, but you can clone just one, then `fetch` the remainder like so:

```
git clone git@github/path/to/repository.git --branch my_branch_1 --single-branch
git fetch origin my_branch_2:my_branch_2 my_branch_3:my_branch_3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick and working answer. I've just tested and it's exactly what I was looking for.
I've just set it trackable later.
> git push --set-upstream origin my_branch_2 
and that's fine.

Comment: Consider using `git remote add -t <branch> origin` to add specific branches. Otherwise the `--single-branch` parameter causes your Git to *not bother* fetching and updating the remaining remote-tracking names that you'd probably like to have.