# Git- Single Branch : How to checkout a new remote branch from a single branch?

Tags: git

The repo I'm working on is huge, approximately 55GB. It has more number of branches & It takes lots of storage space. So I decided to clone a single branch.

I cloned the master branch using the following command.

```
git clone -b master --single-branch <remote-repo-url>
```

I verified that only the `master` branch was cloned by navigating it to the project folder.

Next, I want to check out the `development` branch from the remote. I tried the following command,

```
git checkout --track origin/development
```

and it gives an error `fatal: 'origin/development' is not a commit and a branch 'development' cannot be created from it`

How can I check out a remote branch from a single branch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT: Clone only specific branches from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446026/git-clone-only-specific-branches-from-github)

Answer (score 4):

You need to fetch the development branch first:

```
git fetch origin development:development
```

Consider using

```
git remote add -t development origin_development <remote_url>
```

to add a remote for the specific branches. Otherwise the `--single-branch` parameter causes your Git to not bother fetching and updating the remaining remote-tracking names that you'd probably like to have.

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58446350/2082964)