# Cloned using Git Single Branch, How to checkout other branches?

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, bitbucket

When I cloned single branch. When needing to merge from other branch, other branches doesn't show up.

```
git clone --single-branch --branch release/2.0.0 https://some-repo.com/***.git
```

Nor `git checkout other-branch` recognizes other existing branches on remote.

Can I checkout other branches with-in same folder? Is there a command?

**UPDATE**:

I did try the solution posted here:

```
git fetch origin release/2.0.0 release/2.0.0
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67998814/1431250

**Result:**

> git checkout  release/2.0.0 error: pathspec 'release/2.0.0' did not
> match any file(s) known to git

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GIT: Checkout to a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4479960/git-checkout-to-a-specific-folder)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT No Updated outcome above.

Comment: You didn't follow the instructions. It says `git fetch origin development:development`. You ran `git fetch origin release/2.0.0 release/2.0.0`. It should be `git fetch origin release/2.0.0:release/2.0.0`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+single+branch

Comment: Note that while it's possible to do this without "undoing" the single-branch-ness, it's *better*, for most users, to just undo the single-branch-ness.